# Java: InputStream conventions for data availability, closed state, etc

Tags: java, io

I have an InputStream that is set up to handle local files, but want to add the ability to read from a file over a network at a later time. I assume InputStream is geared for this already.

The problem I am having is, apparently InputStream is not guaranteed to have data available at any given time, and data may become available later. Not sure I'm understanding that correctly. There's no method to determine an absolute size of available data (as number of bytes) or even if the InputStream is closed. It seems like if there's a file there, it *must* have something available. A method that is handling the InputStream is probably going to read from it, and if no data is available, there isn't any reason to keep it around. What's worse is I can't even tell if there *is* any data available.

So my question is, for a file being read over a network or locally, how can I determine if it is open/closed, and possibly determine the size of the file on the other end? Why is this class so bare?

Comment: I understand the client/server dynamic data streaming capability here, but for dealing with files over a network, this isn't a great way to deal with that data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `InputStream` abstract class is for reading bytes from any source, not just a file. Its descendants provide methods for specific sources. For example, `FileInputStream` can be used to read bytes from a file, while `SocketInputStream` is used to read bytes from a socket.

This is why `InputStream` doesn't offer any methods for determining the file size, because it would make no sense for sources other than files.

I'm not sure what exactly you mean by reading file over a network. If it means reading a file from a remote filesystem (e.g. over NFS), then you can use the `length()` method in the `File` class to get the size of the file:

```
File file = new File("/path/to/file");
System.out.println(file.length());
```

You can determine whether the `FileInputStream` is open or not using the `valid()` method on the `FileDescriptor` instance obtained by calling the `getFD()` method on the 'FileInputStream' object:

```
boolean isOpen(FileInputStream stream)
{
    return stream.getFD().valid();
}
```

Of course, bear in mind that the [Law of Leaky Abstractions](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html) applies.

Comment: Assume I connected to a file that is hosted by an HTTP server. The file is known to be static only (no dynamic data) and will always be a fixed size. Is there a class I can use the read from such a file that will give length() and valid() methods, and will also work for local files?

Answer (score 1):

java.io.Inputstream does one thing, and one thing only. It provides an interface for reading bytes of data from... anything. It could be a file, an HTPP website, a database, whatever decided to provide the InputStream. As such, it is bare exactly because that simplicity makes it universal. For example, an InputStream could be used for streaming live television. In that case there is no length of content, since you could stream forever. Thus if InputStream provided a length of content feature, it would become useless for endless streams.

End of the day, you're going to have to use the technology one step up from the input stream to determine things like existence. For example, use File.exists for file existance, look for a 404 error for HTTP non-existence, or a database exception for database non-existence. Only look to the Inputstream when you want to read bytes from the file, because that's all it's intended to do. No more, no less.